# Unity rigidbody refuses to exist despite global scope

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In unity I have been trying to make a script, however for some reason, my Rigidbody variable refuses to exist outside of scope. The errors it gives me reads out: `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object VelocityBasedPlayerMovement.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/VelocityBasedPlayerMovement.cs:80)`

And a very similar error for a previous line.

`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
VelocityBasedPlayerMovement.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/VelocityBasedPlayerMovement.cs:29)`

Here is my code. Notice Rigidbody is set, **the object DOES have a rigid body as the first debug.log displays the name of the object it is on.** But these two lines refuse to work

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class VelocityBasedPlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody rb;
    public int maxSpeed;
    public float speedMult;
    public float acceleration;
    public float decelleration;
    private bool keyNotPressed = false;
    private Vector3 velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    private Vector3 temp = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        /*THIS IS FINE
        Debug.Log("Rigidbody attached to: "+rb.gameObject.name);
        */
        if(rb = null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Could not find Rigid Body!\n" + this.name);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        /*THIS IS AN ERROR
        Debug.Log("Rigidbody attached to: " + rb.gameObject.name);
        */
        // TODO Make these proper controls instead of static keys

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            keyNotPressed = false;
            temp += this.transform.forward;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            keyNotPressed = false;
            temp += -this.transform.forward;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            keyNotPressed = false;
            temp += -this.transform.right;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            keyNotPressed = false;
            temp += this.transform.right;
        }
        else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.None))
        {
            keyNotPressed = true;
            temp = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
        temp = temp.normalized;

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!keyNotPressed)
        {
            if ((velocity + temp).magnitude > maxSpeed)
            {
                velocity = temp;
                Debug.LogWarning("Player is above max speed!\n" + (velocity + temp).magnitude);
            }
            else
            {
                velocity = temp*acceleration;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            velocity -= velocity * decelleration;
        }
       /*Error here too
       rb.velocity = velocity;
       */
    }

}
```

Yes, I know the code shouldnt work as intended, but I am working on that. It is just hard to test it when the Rigidbody refuses to be set properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is being causing by the lines

```cs
if(rb = null)
{
    Debug.LogError("Could not find Rigid Body!\n" + this.name);
}
```

You're setting the RigidBody to null, rather than null-checking it.

Replace the first line with this:

```cs
if(rb == null)
```

Comment: Kieran, this type of issue has a close reason ("caused by a typo"). As such, the question should be closed, not answered.

Comment: @Draco18s I was unaware of this, thanks for the heads up. I don't agree that the question should be closed without an answer or atleast comment though as how else will they discover the issue apart from a vague 'caused by typo' thrown at them?

Comment: Comments along the lines of where the problem is are fine. e.g. "You might want to double check this line: `if(rb = null)`"

Comment: Whilst I'm sure you're correct, I feel like that's borderline should be an answer and not what the use of comments should be for.

Either way, not your fault! Thanks for the heads up, I'll ensure I do that next time.